# Are multiple object key levels supported in input components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput

I am trying to use a `<lightning:input>` component to edit the `Quantity` field on an `OpportunityLineItem` object. The `OpportunityLineItem` object is contained within a Javascript Object as a key, so my data looks like this:

```
dataObject {
  opportunityLineItem: {...},
  dataBoolean: false,
  priceBookEntry: {...}
}
```

While the `<lightning:input>` markup looks like this:

```
<lightning:input label="Quantity" type="number" step="1" value="{!dataObject.opportunityLineItem.Quantity}" />
```

The data binding for this does not appear to be working properly - the quantity does not appear in the `<lightning:input>` component, nor does the `<lightning:input>` component allow its (nonexistent) value to be edited at all.

I also tried this with `<ui:input>` and it doesn't work with that, either.

Is this use case supported for Lightning, and if so, is this a known issue? What workarounds can I use to resolve this?

Comment: It should work. Make sure capitalization and spelling is correct. I'll check this out when I get home.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Did it work for you?